# Using .NET to detect .ogg file properties? Number of channels, bits per channel, sample rate?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, ogg

Does anyone know how to detect various .ogg file properties such as the number of channels, bits per channel, and the sample rate?

I would like to do this without using DirectX, can anyone recommend a library that could do it.  Can anyone recommend an open-source library that could do it, which could be called from managed code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out and wrote about it:

http://ellismis.com/2012/01/06/using-c-net-to-detect-ogg-vorbis-file-properties/

Answer (score 1):

I think [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) can do this, but I'm not entirely sure. I know it can encode audio *to* ogg, but I'm not sure if it can read existing ogg files.

A StackOverflow user has posted a piece of code for working with ogg files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152967/14606

Comment: I posted the same question to the NAudio forum earlier, hopefully someone there can give me some feedback.  Thanks for linking me to that bit of code, if I end up rolling my own, that looks like a great place to start!

Comment: Mark Heath (the author of NAudio) is an SO user - perhaps he will see this and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of a library, but the file format looks pretty sane. You should be able to write some fairly trivial code to do this.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#File_format

Comment: This looks like a worst case scenario for me.  I feel like it is something I could spend all weekend hacking on and arrive at a half-broken solution.  I primarily do web development and get a little anxious when going that low level :)