# Checking ogg file properties with C# (especially the loop timecode) - possible?

Tags: c#, ogg

Basically: Is there a way to check the properties of an ogg file with C#... Especially the loop timecode is what i want to read.

Comment: Are you just extracting information, or are you playing the file in c# as well? If you are, what library are you using to decode?

Comment: There's not enough detail in the question to know if you want to read just tags or properties of the audio, too (in which case, possible duplicate of [Using .NET to detect .ogg file properties? Number of channels, bits per channel, sample rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668767/using-net-to-detect-ogg-file-properties-number-of-channels-bits-per-channel)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `LOOPSTART` and `LOOPEND` metadata, as suggested [here](https://wohlsoft.ru/pgewiki/How_To:_Looping_music_files#How_to_make_looping_OGG_on_Audacity_example), or `LOOPSTART` and `LOOPLENGTH`, as suggested [here](https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?threads/make-looping-bgm-part-1-ogg-vorbis.10987/), these are saved as [`comments`](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/v-comment.html) in the audio file.

Using [NVorbis](https://github.com/ioctlLR/NVorbis) (also on Nuget), you can read the comments like this:

```
using(var f = new VorbisReader(@"c:\myloop.ogg")) {
    foreach(var c in f.Comments) {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

Your output will look like

```
LOOPSTART=0
TITLE=My title
DATE=2018
LOOPEND=26508
ARTIST=Artist name
```

Comment: This technicaly works, but it seems the ogg files in my specific case don't have the LOOP comments, even though they do loop. Can it be that the loop is stored somewhere else in the oggfile and that this can be found via the VorbisReader?

Comment: How do they loop? When played in what software?